# Resharper not detecting global variables inside angular services

Tags: javascript, resharper

I want to detect places in my code, where globals are used, so I can do something about it.
I have a service like this:

```
myApp.service("myService", function () {

    function f1() {
        var a = global.someVar;
    }

    function f2() {
        global.f();
    }

    function f3() {
        global = "a";
    }

});
```

Problem is, variable "global" in f1() isn't detected as global variable, in f2() it also isn't detected, but in f3() case I get "Assignment to implicitly declared global variable", while it should be detected in all 3 cases.

In Resharper JS Inspection sererity options, I have all turned on.

I tried to wrap my code in self invoking function, but still no success. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make Resharper detect globals in theese situations?

Comment: If you tried to wrap your code in scoping functions, did you also tried to put the global variable as an parameter in that function? `(function(global){  ...  })()`

Comment: I do not want to put it there, because I need first to detect global variables (make Resharper color them red), so after that I can remove them, use DI to inject them, etc. The problem is, that global detection is not working as expected.

Comment: Ok. That's the other way around. I was using JSHint linters for that. Don't know about Resharper ... :(